# AOP with Grails

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy, aop

I want to create a custom logging annotation in my Grails project.

My code:

```
class MyService{
    @AuditLog
    def method1() {
        println "method1 called"
        method2()
    }
    @AuditLog
    def method2() {
        println "method2 called"
    }
}
```

Interceptor:

```
class AuditLogInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
        println "${methodInvocation.method}"
        return methodInvocation.proceed();
    }
}
```

Spring config:

```
aop {
    config("proxy-target-class": true) {
        pointcut(id: "auditLogInterceptorPointcut", expression: "@annotation(xxx.log.AuditLog)")
        advisor('pointcut-ref': "auditLogInterceptorPointcut", 'advice-ref': "auditLogInterceptor")
    }
}

auditLogInterceptor(AuditLogInterceptor) {}
```

The result:

```
public java.lang.Object xxx.MyService.method1()
method1 called
method2 called
```

I would like to see the annotation fire for method 2 as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because the internal method calls in the service class to self are **not** done on the proxied instance of the `service` class. If you fetch the service bean from the application context and try to call `method2()` you should see the `aspect` listening to the `advice`.

```
class MyService{
    static transactional = false
    def grailsApplication

    @AuditLog
    def method1() {
        println "method1 called"
        grailsApplication.mainContext.myService.method2()
        //method2()
    }
    @AuditLog
    def method2() {
        println "method2 called"
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice insight! I think it'd be great if Grails provides some magic to delegate calls to methods in the same service class to the proxy class.