# Grails: How to reference Service itself and use it in Java?

Tags: grails, service, reference

A **SomeService** is defined and in a closure it is passed to a Java class:

```
package somepackage

class SomeService{
    ...
    def process(){
        ...
        //here, how to reference [thisService]? this keyword?
        //I tried this keyword, but an exception occurs
        JavaClass javaObject = new JavaClass(thisService, otherParams)
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Exception is thrown when using **this** referring to **SomeService**:

```
Groovyc: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: somepackage/SomeService
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1791)
at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:318)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:263)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:957)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:952)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getSuperClass(ClassNode.java:946)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFrom(ClassNode.java:889)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.assignmentCastAndVisit(AsmClassGenerator.java:4049)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.evaluateEqual(AsmClassGenerator.java:4002)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitDeclarationExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:1468)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit(DeclarationExpression.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitAndAutoboxBoolean(AsmClassGenerator.java:4111)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.evaluateExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:1437)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitReturnStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:1398)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ReturnStatement.visit(ReturnStatement.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:35)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:165)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:728)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:616)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:591)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:686)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1039)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:276)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$12.call(CompilationUnit.java:748)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:942)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:519)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:497)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:474)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:54)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.main(GroovycRunner.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: entrust.EnTrustService
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
... 43 more
```

My question is: how to reference the service itself to other classes? if **this** is applicable, is this problem related to the calling class being Java class other than groovy class?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to `someService` bean from `ApplicationContext` as:

```
class SomeService{
    def grailsApplication

    def process(){
        ...
        //here, how to reference [thisService]? this keyword?
        //I tried this keyword, but an exception occurs
        JavaClass javaObject = 
            new JavaClass(grailsApplication.mainContext.someService, otherParams)
        ...
    }
}
```

Doing this, the control goes out of the proxy and fetches the bean from the context. This same principle is applied in transactions or any aspects (AOP) related transition from one method to other in the same service class. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410018/aop-with-grails/17414393#17414393).

Comment: Hi, seems grailsApplication is only injected into SomeController, not into SomeService. I tried this tweak but the exception remained.

Comment: Also you can get reference to it like following

'Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean("someService")'

Comment: @dmahapatro I tested your advice and failed, same exception showed up. **Holders** comes from which package?